# How to reliably check the source of a paclet in the paclet repository?

Tags: paclets

How does one reliably check the source of a paclet at https://resources.wolframcloud.com/PacletRepository/ ?

At the bottom of a paclet there is PACLET SOURCE (which in my opinion should be at the very top and easy to find) where there is DefinitionNotebook and Github Link.

I do not understand the definition notebook. I opened the notebook and tried clicking on a .wl file to open it and that did not open the file.

The GitHub link does not seem reliable to me as I see no guarantee that the current version of the GitHub repository corresponds to what is in the paclet repository when it is installed.